# Arrow heads on raphael path

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I'm fairly new to raphael.js and I'm trying to draw an arrow head on raphael path element (or draw and arrow from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2))
This is the raphael path (line) that I draw from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) on my paper.
Assuming that x1,y1,x2 and y2 all have expected values.

```
var arrow = paper.path("M"+x1+","+y1+"L"+x2+","+y2);
arrow.attr({stroke:'red'});
```

Is there a way to include arrow heads on either/both side of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use raphael's arrow-start and arrow-end.

```
arrow.attr({
    "arrow-start":"classic-wide-long",
    "arrow-end":"classic-wide-long"
}):
```